# Python Program to Match Lines in File

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in python that reads through a .txt file and checks

```
If line[i] == line [i+12]:
    print line[i]
```

So far, I have:

```
f=open('file.txt', "r")

count=0
for line in f:
    while count < 1000:
        print(count)
        if line(count) == line(count+12):
            print (line(count))
        count+=1
```

My output is 1000 zeros.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No, your output is a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Please post your actual code if you want it debugged.

Comment: Also, are you trying to print all lines where the 13th character is the same as the first, or all lines that are the same as the line 12 lines later?

Comment: @abarnert: it looks to me like the OP is mixing spaces and tabs, so it's possible that 1000 zeroes really *is* the output..

Comment: Can you please provide working program with example of input and expected output.

Comment: pretty sure you mean `line[count]`, if you need the i-th character that is. Plus, using index like that will get you a `KeyError` sooner or later.

Comment: Also, you're mixing Python 2.x and 3.x `print` syntax. Which Python version are you actually using?

Comment: @DSM: I'm not sure how that could print 1000 `0`s. If you don't get to the `count+=1`, it'll print an infinite number of `0`s, not 1000. And if you do… well, that _would_ print the numbers from 0 to 999, except that the `line(count)` is going to raise the `TypeError` before you can get there.

Comment: @abarnert: it was the infinite zeroes case I was thinking of, which certainly starts off with 1000 zeroes.  I tend to take beginners' descriptions of things pretty loosely, which has served me pretty well in the past. :^)

Comment: @DSM: I suppose you're right that infinity > 1000. I stopped counting before I got that far. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to print all lines where any character is the same as the one 12 characters later:

```
for line in f:
    for i, c in enumerate(line[:-12]):
        if c == line[i+12]:
            print(line)
            break
```

---

If you're trying to print all lines that are the same as the one 12 lines later, it's simpler in that you only need one loop, but more complicated in that you have an *iterator* of lines, not a list, so you can't randomly access it like this.

One simple fix for that, if the file is small enough, is to *make* a list:

```
lines = list(f)
for i, line in enumerate(lines[:-12]):
    if line == lines[i+12]:
        print(line)
```

---

A better fix is to use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to create a shifted copy of the iterator (which would actually work for either problem):

```
lines, lines12 = itertools.tee(f, 2)
lines12 = islice(lines12, 12, None)
for line, line12 in zip(lines, lines12):
    if line == line12:
        print(line)
```

(If you're using Python 2.x, you will want to use `itertools.izip` here, not `zip`. And you also probably want to take the parentheses off all your `print`s.)

---

Either way, I have no idea what you're even trying to do with `count`. If you want to keep a count of matches along the way, move the `count = 0` outside the loop, and do `count += 1` each time you print something, but don't try to use it to index the lines or anything like that.

Comment: that's pretty advanced python :-)

Comment: You can keep parenthesis around the print statement in Python 2.x, it works as expected.

Comment: @Hoffmann: It really isn't that advanced, and a lot of problems get a whole lot simpler once you think of them in terms of "how do I transform this iterator into the one I want" instead of "how do I stumble around through all this data". David Beazley has some great [presentations](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) that explain it better than I can. (Also, thinking in terms of "lazy lists" instead of "iterators" and "generators" seems to help a lot of people grasp the idea.)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: … except when you try to, e.g., print multiple values, in which case it works _differently_ than expected, by printing a tuple… or when you post your code on StackOverflow and mislead people into thinking you're using Python 3 and giving you answers that don't work for you. … or…

Comment: @abarnert Definitively worth knowing more functions of the standard library from heart

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` @abarnert

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Sure, but if you're writing code that uses a future statement, and post it to SO without including the future statement, you're going to mislead people into thinking you're using Python 3 when you aren't, and giving you answers that don't work for you. Unless you have a way to import SO from the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f
  for line in f:
    if len(buffer) < 12:
      buffer.append[line]
      continue
    if line == buffer[0]:
      print line
    buffer = buffer[1:11] + [line]
```

Comment: That would be the solution for a really big file that you don't want to read completely into RAM

Comment: … or you can let `tee` take care of the buffering for you, which is a lot more concise, conceptually simpler, and probably even faster. But it's definitely worth it for the OP to understand how to write a buffer on his own!